# Querying Freebase to get all relations between two concepts

Tags: freebase

I'd like to query Freebase in order to obtain all the relations that occur between two concepts.

My problem is that I'd like to do this using two concepts' names.

For example: I have "Ball" as a concept (and I don't want to say to Freebase if it is Ball as in Dance or as in Sports Equipment) and I want to find out if there are relations between it and "Football" (in this case, there is just one concept on Freebase for Football, so it is easier); the ouput should be "/sports/sports_equipment/sport_used_for".

For now I just managed to do the same query using the id of the concepts, but I would like to search for relations as I explained before, without knowing the exact meaning of the concept title (Ball in the example).

The query that I have so far is this:

```
    {
      "type": "/type/link",
      "source": {
        "id": "/m/0dpm1v"
      },
      "master_property": null,
      "target": {
        "id": "/m/02vx4"
      }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

"name" was what I was looking for. I don't know because I did not try/find this before.

Thak you anyway.

```
    {
      "type": "/type/link",
      "source": {
      "name": "ball"
      },
      "master_property": null,
      "target": {
      "name": "football"
      }
    }
```